# Extortion attempt

Tags: fraud

If an extortion attempt is made telling the victim to deposit a specific amount to a bitcoin account "or else" what law enforcement agency takes lead?  How can one determine the jurisdiction of an account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If an extortion attempt is made telling the victim to deposit a specific amount to a bitcoin account "or else" what law enforcement agency takes lead?

Assuming that you're in the United States, the FBI.

https://www.fbi.gov/contact-us/when

> How can one determine the jurisdiction of an account?

You can't, particularly if they've never used that address before. It sounds like that's what they've done, assuming they want to know when each person has paid up.

If you pay the ransom, and they deposit the money into an exchange, then you have somewhere to start. Of course, if they just sit on the money for the next five years, you don't have anything to go on. Either way, this isn't easy.